# how to install freeipa server ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, server, package-management, dpkg

hello sir please tell how to install freeipa serevr on ubuntu 20.04  that time i am starting installation i was found same error so please help

```
dell@ipa:~$ sudo apt -y install freeipa-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package freeipa-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'freeipa-server' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: It is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freeipa/+bug/1875114  Your best alternative is probably the docker container: https://www.freeipa.org/page/Downloads